# How to check how many "blank" AdSense ads are displayed?

Tags: google-adsense

[When AdSense does not have adds prepared for user it displays blank space](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/113262?hl=en). Is there a simple way to check how many of my page views end up without ads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is "Coverage" column in AdSense reports which reports the value.